# Oracle Error(36,14): PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

This is really annoying me, so I am reaching out...

I have a Oracle SQL procedure and a couple of objects declared inside a package.

```
TYPE myRecord IS RECORD (
    myVal INTEGER
);
myTab IS TABLE OF myRecord;
procedure myProc(myCollection IN myTab);
```

Inside the package body I am trying to select from myCollection. In Oracle 12c simply using the TABLE function works fine.

```
BEGIN
    SELECT myVal FROM TABLE(myCollection);
```

In version lower, 11.2 for example I seem to get Error(36,14): PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item.

I have looked at other answers but am no clearer to understanding what I need to do make it work.

Comment: in 11.2 and earlier, you can't use a PL/SQL declared type inside a SQL statement - instead, you need to declare the type at the schema level (i.e. `create or replace type ...`).

Comment: @Boneist Is the syntax that same inside the procedure if the type is globally declared?

Comment: Yes; if you create a global type of mytab, you would use that in your procedure parameters in the same way you would if you declared the mytab type in the package. It's just the scope is wider - i.e. outside of the package.